# TypeError: n is undefined in underscore template

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, pug

I am using underscore temperating in jade.

**index.jade**

```
extends layout
block content
  .wrap
    .container-fluid#container


script(type='text/template' id='main-template')
  .row
        .col-xs-8.col-sm-9
          .heading h2 Welcome to the Node Chatroom
          hr/
          .content
            ul.list-group#chatList
        .col-xs-4.col-sm-3
          .sidePanel
            .panel-heading
              h3.panel-title Online Users
                span.badge pull-right#userCount
            hr/
            .panel-body
              ul.list-group#userList      

      .push
  .footer
    .container-fluid
      .row
        form
          .form-group
            .col-xs-8.col-sm-9
              input(type="text" id="chatInput" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Write a message here..." rows="3")
            .col-xs-4.col-sm-3
              button(id="send-message-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit") Send Message

script(type='text/template' id='login-template')
  .row
    .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4.text-center
      .login
        .form-group
          label Enter name
          input(type="text" class="form-control" id="nameText")
          .btn-group
            button(id="name" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg") Login
```

**Main.js**

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#login-template').html()),


    events: {
        'click #name': 'onLogin'
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
    this.vent = options.vent;

    this.listenTo(this.model, "change:error", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    onLogin: function() {
    //this.l.start();
    this.vent.trigger("login", this.$('#nameText').val());
    }
});
```

It is showing *TypeError: n is undefined* on line `template: _.template($('#login-template').html()),`

I have tried using . after script as proposed in [jade doc](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) . but it didn't work.

Looks like underscore cant access the #login-template id. Any reason why?

Comment: Are you importing underscore? If you're not, you should do it in your main file. `var _ = require("underscore");`

Comment: If you couldn't get at `#login-template` then you'd get an error complaining about `undefined` not having a `replace` method or something similar. Have you looked at `$('#login-template').html()` to see what's there? Why are you giving the template function data when there is no Underscore markup in the template?

Comment: try shifting  template: _.template($('#login-template').html()), to render function. like this.template: _.template($('#login-template').html())

Comment: @muistooshort yes, it have the contents of #login-template. its in next template.

Comment: I see some Jade stuff but what does `$('#login-template').html()` actually give you?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error. Then below one solved me.

```
var template= _.template($('#myTemplate').html());
```

This may help you.

[typeerror-n-is-undefined-in-underscore-min-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320215/typeerror-n-is-undefined-in-underscore-min-js)

Comment: Please add some information/description/context about the link even if it is on SO itself